After reloading/ refreshing the page in Express.js the JWT token is removed from the Cookies
After logging the user, jwt token is stored in the Application tab but when I refresh the page token is removed from the Application tab. I wanted to send the token cookies from the front end to the server side but it's not happening as the cookies are not stored. In the front end I am using axios and all the cors policy is satisfied and cookie parse is working but still the token is not saved


const verifyToken = async (req, res, next) => {
  const token  = req.cookie?.token
  console.log("verified token :",token);
  
  if(!token) {
    return res.status(403).send({ message:"unauthorize" })
  }
  jwt.verify(token, process.env.BUCKET_TOKEN,(err, decoded) => {
    if(err){
      console.log("Access Denied :",err);
      return res.status(401).send({message:"Unauthorize User"})  
    }
    req.user = decoded 
    next()
  })

}

 // creating jwt token
    app.post("/jwt", async (req, res) => {
      const user = req.body;
      console.log(user);

      try {
        const token = jwt.sign(user, process.env.BUCKET_TOKEN, {
          expiresIn: `1h`,
        });
        console.log("token:", token);

        res
          .cookie("token", token, {
            httpOnly: true,
            secure: false,
            sameSite: "None",
            maxAge: 3600000,
            path: '/'
          })
          .send({ success: "true", token });
      } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).send({
          success: false,
          message: "Failed to create token",
          error: error.message,
        });
      }
    });

 // Endpoint to fetch Booking data by email
    app.get("/bookings", verifyToken, async (req, res) => {
      const email = req.query.email;
      
      console.log("Verifying the token ", req.user);
      if(email !==req.user) {return res.status(403).send({ message:"Forbidden" })} 
      
      // console.log("Fetching booking for email : ", email);
      if (!email) {
        return res.status(400).send({ message: "Email query is required" });
      }
      try {
        
        const query = { email: email };
        const result = await bookingCollection.find(query).toArray();
        res.send(result);
      } catch (error) {
        res
          .status(500)
          .send({ message: "Failed to fetch booking", error: error.message });
      }
    });




The token is usually stored on the localStorage on the client side. You can send the token to your server through a request header usually named "authorization". It should look like this req.headers.authorization

localstorage is not that secure so i am storing the token in cookies for seurity purpose.And i finally fix the bug in code, the reason why token remove after refresh was , secure : false , i set the secure: true now its working
